# preview not working on neovim 0.5 on windows 10 with fzf

Tags: vim, neovim, fzf

i'm running neovim 0.5 with fzf-vim on windows 10 and can't seem to make preview to work.

my init.vim per below:

```
call plug#begin('~/AppData/Local/nvim/plugged')

    Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } }
    Plug 'junegunn/fzf.vim'
call plug#end()

let g:fzf_layout = { 'window': { 'width': 0.9, 'height': 0.9 } }
let $FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS="--ansi --preview-window 'right:60%' --layout reverse --margin=1,4"
```

Error msg i got when previewing files using :Files or :Rg command:                                        /mnt/c/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/nvim/plugged/fzf.vim/bin/preview.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/c/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/nvim/plugged/fzf.vim/bin/preview.sh: line 5: $'\r': command not found
/mnt/c/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/nvim/plugged/fzf.vim/bin/preview.sh: line 40: syntax error near unexpected token
/mnt/c/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/nvim/plugged/fzf.vim/bin/preview.sh: line 40: `  elif [ -n "$MSWINHOME" ]; then

have confirmed that bash.exe from c:\Program Files\Git\bin\  is in `PATH`.

Comment: Do you have the latest fzf installed along with the fzf.vim plugin?

Comment: correct me if im wrong, Plug 'junegunn/fzf', { 'do': { -> fzf#install() } } will ensure the install of latest fzf?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Install [Git for Windows](https://git-scm.com/download/win) if you **haven't** already installed it.
2. Add the following line to your ***init.vim*** file.

   let $PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;" . $PATH
3. Save and Reload NeoVim.

Comment: not too sure about the meaning of `let $PATH = "C:\Program\ Files\Git\usr\bin;" . $PATH` but it doesn't work. Also tried `let $PATH = "C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;" . $PATH`. Confirmed that the git is installed in C:\program files\git folder.

Comment: okay it is working now after changing the path to ` let $PATH = "C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin;" . $PATH`. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

i solved it adding `"C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin"` to the PATH environment variable in Windows 10